# Can we do Hideandshow for an entire class using react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

In my App.js I have two classes. So, when I click on add button in one class then the second classes view should be displayed by hiding the first classes view.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about classes then you can do it like this:

```js
  const Foo = () => {
     const [showClass, setShowClass] = useState(false);
     return (
        <div>
          <div className={showClass ? "showClass" : "hideClass">
              Only show after click
          </div>
          <div className={!showClass ? "showClass" : "hideClass"}>
              Show when not clicked
          </div>
          <button onClick={() => setShowClass(true)}>Click me</button>
        </div>
     )
  };
```

However in react the convention is to not use classes but instead do conditional rendering:

```
  const Foo = () => {
     const [showElement, setShowElement] = useState(false);
     return (
        <div>
          {
            showElement ?
              <div>
                  Only show after click
              </div>
            :
              <div>
                  Show when not clicked
              </div>
          }

          <button onClick={() => setShowElement(true)}>Click me</button>
        </div>
     )
  };
```